# Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error: While run nodejs project: WSH

Tags: node.js, compiler-errors, nodemon, node-api

Getting this error while run nodejs project.
Following below commands.

```
nodemon --exec src/app.js
nodemon --exec src/server.js
```

[image: Getting this error while run nodejs project]

Below are the dependency

[image: Dependancy]

Comment: Seems like your `.js` files are associated with the Windows Scripting Host (`wscript.exe`).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Windows Script Host Error: Invalid character - Code:800A03F6 - Source: Microsoft JScript compilation error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70045198/windows-script-host-error-invalid-character-code800a03f6-source-microsoft) *(Answer points to file association issue)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I have resolved the issue by installing ESM.

```
npm install --save esm
```

And then run

```
node -r esm src/server.js
```