# ANGULAR - Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I am facing the issue ,

**Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands**

everytime while using any of the ng command

Comment: what command you are trying to run?

Comment: ng new projectname or any command with ng is not running

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: what angular version are you using? please check https://angular.io/cli/version

Comment: If you try `ng --version` with angular cli 14, you will get that error. Please use `ng version` instead.

Comment: What? why? what are they doing there?

Answer (score 134):

Uninstall Angular old version & Install latest version (14)

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli 
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Use:

```
ng version | ng v
```

Instead of:

```
ng -v | ng --version
```

Answer (score 47):

I was also facing the same issue while running the `ng --version`. I tried to uninstall and reinstall but it didn't work. With cli 14, `ng --version` doesn't work.

So use `ng version` instead.

Answer (score 33):

I actually upgraded ng version just a day ago. I faced same problem. This happened because the current version in your system got depreciated ( no longer in use). So you have to update ng version in your system.

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

this will help to update your angular version in your system and to check, you have to give `ng version` instead `ng --version`.

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: "Current version" of what? What was tyou deprecated version a what is new version?

Answer (score 16):

```
ng v
```

After upgrading to the new version I am facing an error with ng --version cmd, but I am able to see the angular version with **ng v**

[image]

Answer (score 11):

```
ng --version
```

Error: You need to specify a command before moving on. Use '--help' to view the available commands.

1. Check your node version.

```
node --version v16.16.0 (new version)
```

2. type

```
ng v
```

Answer (score 8):

for window 10 use `ng v` command only, and also check environment variable.

Answer (score 5):

### Try it with Power Shell

Usually, the default terminal is **Command Prompt**.

Change that to **Power Shell** and try it again. For some reason, Command Prompt can not execute Angular CLI commands, at least in my end.

---

In you are using VS Code, you can check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69040763/14389830) how to change default terminal.

Answer (score 3):

It is showing error beacuse you are run your command in **command prompt** and `ng --version` is used to run on **git bash**, so either you have to use git bash to run `ng --version` command or you need to just write `ng v` on **command prompt**.

Answer (score 3):

### Shell incompatibility in Windows

For me I discovered it was a Shell incompatibility. The only one that recognize **ng commands** is ***PowerShell***.

These below show the same error:

- CMDER
- GitBash
- CMD

Hopefully this will be fixed in the future.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to specify the command. Try to put 'ng version', but before that, you should make sure that you have Angular CLI

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and the uninstall/install angular cli didn't solve it.

What worked for me :
There was a path to C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\npm\ and another one to C:\Users*username*\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli

I removed the second path and restarted my CMD console

It worked again.

Answer (score 0):

try running command prompt as Admin and then run-
npm install -g @angular/cli

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling and Installing @angular/cli did not work for me
this answer fixed it

> make sure you have proper path variable configured as shown below
> Go to your system variable settings
> [path variable snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TXBgI.png)
> make sure you have all these mentioned as part of path C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm C:\Program Files\nodejs

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71602204/6314006

Make sure to edit the path under **System variables**.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32345337)